# How can I use a string within the tree of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I am getting the path to a value in PHP, but not sure how to combine the array with a stringed path? The following gives me a value.

```
var_dump($array['boo']['far'][0]); // works
```

While none of these give me a valid (or are even valid PHP).

```
$path = "['boo']['far'][0]";
var_dump($array.$path); // doesn't work
var_dump($array{$path}); // doesn't work
var_dump(eval($array.$path)); // doesn't work
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string components of the path are fairly simple, you could parse the path into components using [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and then recursively go through the levels of the array to find the desired element:

```
$array['boo']['far'][0] = "hello world!\n";
$path = "['boo']['far'][0]";

preg_match_all("/\['?([^\]']+)'?\]/", $path, $matches);
$v = $array;
foreach ($matches[1] as $p) {
    $v = $v[$p];
}
echo $v;
```

Output:

```
hello world!
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XGliK)

Other than that, your only real alternative is [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). You can use `eval` to echo the value, or to assign it to another variable. For example,

```
$array['boo']['far'][0] = "hello world!\n";
$path = "['boo']['far'][0]";
eval("echo \$array$path;");
eval("\$x = \$array$path;");
echo $x;
$y = eval("return \$array$path;");
echo $y;
```

Output:

```
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XZWaG)

Comment: I figured eval() was the only way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottFoster not sure if you saw but I did just edit with an alternate way. Always good to avoid `eval` if you can.

Comment: i'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You have an **array**.

Depending on what you want to do with it, you can either add the string as *part* of the first index:

```
$result = $array['boo']['far'][0] . $path;
```

Or **push** it to the next index of the array:

```
array_push($array['boo']['far'], $path);
```